# React router with dynamic array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create a dynamic router based on my page list. But I can't define my components.
Link path and component names are coming to my list.
Is there any solution to this?

```
import Home from "../pages/Home";

import BannerManagement from "../pages/BannerManagement";
```

My page list in App.js

```
const pageList= [
  {
    path: "home",
    element: "Home",
  },
  {
    path: "BannerManagement",
    element: "BannerManagement",
  }
];
```

in App.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <BrowserRouter>
              {
                pageList.map(page=>{
                return (<Route exact path={"/"+page.path} component={page.element}/>)
              })
            }
            </BrowserRouter>
      </Router>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What version of react router dom you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageList` array in `App.js` should store the component reference instead of a string of the component name.

Render the routes into a `Switch` component so routes are *exclusively* matched, and make sure the routes are specified in *inverse* order of path specificity in the `pageList` array, e.g. `"/foo/bar"` listed prior to `"/foo"`. This allows *more* specific routes to be matched before falling back to *less* specific routes. This effectively removes the need to specify the `exact` prop everywhere.

You also need only one router component to provide a routing context to the entire app.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from "../pages/Home";
import BannerManagement from "../pages/BannerManagement";
...

const pageList= [
  {
    path: "/home",
    element: Home, // <-- component reference
  },
  {
    path: "/BannerManagement",
    element: BannerManagement, // <-- component reference
  },
  ...
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      {pageList.map(page => (
        <Route path={page.path} component={page.element} />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```